Arbitrage-Free, Breeden-Litzenberger and Risk-Neutral Measure
Let $\sigma_{\text{BS}}(K, T)$ a given IV slice at $T$, which is implied by a price slice $C(K, T)$.
From this price slice, we can infer the Risk Neutral density of the price distribution at $T$ using the Breeden-Litzenberger as :
$$f_{\mathbb{Q}}(S_T) = \partial_{KK} C(K, T)$$
If the slice is arbitrage-free, does it mean necessarly that :
$$\int S_T f_{\mathbb{Q}}(S_T) dS_T = S_0$$
If so, I can shift the implied volatility and still get a convex price curve but for which the mean of the density will be shifted.

If the volatility increases (say), the tails of $f(S_T)$ would get fatter but the mean ought to stay the same.
